# Logged out when switching tty

Tags: debian, tty, x-server, lightdm

I ugraded my Debian from Stretch to Buster. Now each time I switch the tty (by Ctrl-Alt-FX) from my graphical instance (F7) to something else (e.g. F1) and back, I have to login again. It seems that LightDM is restarted. I am sure that this was not the case when I used Stretch. Is there any way to reconfigure this?

Comment: Is it a real login, or is it just the screen saver that has started and locked the screen?

Comment: A real login. In particular, all previously opened windows are gone.

Comment: Okay … I think this is related to the following bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1662057. The XServer crashes and the error is the same: “modeset(0): failed to set mode: Invalid argument”

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add that information.

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04 using the Xubuntu lightdm setup.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for **Intel graphics users only** and not Nouveau or Nvidia users.

I found the answer to this question on [bugzilla.freedesktop.org](https://bugzilla.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109668) and [the solution](https://bugzilla.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109668#c18) was posted by Jan Kratochvil.

It seems you need to force the Intel driver for X11.

First, on Debian and Ubuntu, you will need to create the following directory:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

Now, run the following command to create the needed config file:

```
sudo bash -c 'cat >/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf <<EOH
# https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1630367#c18
# https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1697591
# https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1662057
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics"
    Driver "intel"
EndSection
EOH'
```

I did this and then switched to TTY1, then to TTY6, and back to TTY7 and I was logged off. I logged back in and switched TTYs again and I was not logged off. However, I did have to redo the settings for my external monitor.